# Unable to build has_and_belongs_to_many relation in Rspec with FactoryBot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I read the documentation of FactoryBot here: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_bot/file/GETTING_STARTED.md

I have users and roles and it is a has_and_belongs_to_many relation. I have tried many steps from the documentation to setup this relation but nothing works.

First, I tried this technique:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :role do
    name { "marketing" }

    factory :admin_role do
      name { "admin" }
    end
  end
end

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user, aliases: [:marketing] do
    email { 'marketing@mysite.io' }
    password { '123456' }
    password_confirmation { '123456' }
    association :role
  end
end
```

But it gives me:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `role=' for #<User:0x007f9743449198>
```

Second, I tried this technique:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :role do
    name { "marketing" }

    factory :admin_role do
      name { "admin" }
    end
  end
end

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user, aliases: [:marketing] do
    email { 'marketing@mysite.io' }
    password { '123456' }
    password_confirmation { '123456' }
    role
  end
end
```

But again I get this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `role=' for #<User:0x007f9743449198>
```

Third, I tried this technique of pluralizing the relation:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :role do
    name { "marketing" }

    factory :admin_role do
      name { "admin" }
    end
  end
end

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user, aliases: [:marketing] do
    email { 'marketing@mysite.io' }
    password { '123456' }
    password_confirmation { '123456' }
    role
  end
end
```

I get this error:

```
ArgumentError: Trait not registered: roles
```

Yet when I read the documentation, it suggests I can use these methods. So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will work but since a user can have many roles you probably need to add a role as a single array item

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user, aliases: [:marketing] do
    email { 'marketing@mysite.io' }
    password { '123456' }
    password_confirmation { '123456' }
    roles { [ role ] }
  end
end
```

Or

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user, aliases: [:marketing] do
    email { 'marketing@mysite.io' }
    password { '123456' }
    password_confirmation { '123456' }
    roles { [ create(role) ] }
  end
end
```

The reason for your error is you can't call `@user.role` but you can call `@user.roles` with HABTM relation.